# How to get rid of redundant Ctrl_L event when AltGr key is pressed?

Tags: keyboard, citrix

I'm logging in to a remote Linux system through Citrix to a Windows machine and then through an additional remote desktop solution to the Linux machine. Unfortunately, there is a bug somewhere in the Citrix part, so that when I press Alt-Gr on a German keyboard, the system receives extra key events, which mess up the interpretation. In the end any combination with Alt-Gr (most of the time) doesn't work. With `xev` pressing the Alt-Gr key alone looks like:

```
KeyPress event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x2600001,
    root 0xf3, subw 0x2600002, time 678212244, (37,36), root:(84,104),
    state 0x0, keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x2600001,
    root 0xf3, subw 0x2600002, time 678212253, (37,36), root:(84,104),
    state 0x4, keycode 108 (keysym 0xfe03, ISO_Level3_Shift), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 92
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x2600001,
    root 0xf3, subw 0x2600002, time 678212340, (37,36), root:(84,104),
    state 0x84, keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x2600001,
    root 0xf3, subw 0x2600002, time 678212351, (37,36), root:(84,104),
    state 0x80, keycode 108 (keysym 0xfe03, ISO_Level3_Shift), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 92
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Note the extra `Control_L` which shouldn't be there. *Without* this intermediate Citrix (only the remote desktop solution), it would work and look like

```
KeyPress event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x2600001,
    root 0xf3, subw 0x2600002, time 679278220, (37,44), root:(84,112),
    state 0x0, keycode 108 (keysym 0xfe03, ISO_Level3_Shift), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 92
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x2600001,
    root 0xf3, subw 0x2600002, time 679278313, (37,44), root:(84,112),
    state 0x80, keycode 108 (keysym 0xfe03, ISO_Level3_Shift), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 92
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

which works just fine.

Currently, there is no easy way to fix the intermediate Citrix.

*Do you know a hack to force the first case to forget the extra `Control_L` (or make it automatically release)?*

If somehow the system would see my `ISO_Level3_Shift` with a `state 0x0`, it would probably work.

Comment: That sounds really difficult. Your best bet may be to change the keyboard layout on Windows, if Citrix won't fix this bug. Or bypass Citrix altogether — there are other, simpler, cheaper ways to access a Linux machine from a Windows machine.

Comment: We have a different way, but we may be required to go through another virtualization layer with Citrix :( I've tried changing Windows keyboard layouts in many different ways, but none of them seem to improve the situation (reproducibly). Let me know if you think a particular configuration of the layouts (Local computer, Citrix, Linux) would make sense.